# Android App - Error Crashing - ListView SetAdapter

Tags: java, android

```
    fragment_text.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/TextFragment_layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".TextFragment">
    
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="@string/welcome" />
    
    </FrameLayout>
    
    TextFragment.java
    package com.example.tourguide;
    
    import android.content.res.Resources;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
    
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    
    /**
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
     * Use the {@link TextFragment#newInstance} factory method to
     * create an instance of this fragment.
     */
    public class TextFragment extends Fragment
    {
        TextView textView;
    
    
        // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
        // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
        private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
        private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    
        // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
        private String mParam1;
        private String mParam2;
    
        public TextFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }
    
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment TextFragment.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        public static TextFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) 
        {
            TextFragment fragment = new TextFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
            args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (getArguments() != null)
            {
                mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
                mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
            }
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup 
        container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_text, container, 
        false);
            textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            return view;
        }
    
        public void updateTextView(int index)
        {
            if(index==0)
            {
                
        textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.set_Richmond));
            }
            else if(index==1)
            {
                
        textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.set_Vancouver));
            }
            else if(index==2)
            {
                
        textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.set_Toronto));
            }
            else if(index==3)
            {
                
        textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.set_New_West));
            }
            else if(index==4)
            {
                
        textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.set_Montreal));
            }
            else if(index==5)
            {
                
        textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.set_Aldergrove));
            }
        }
    
            public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener
        {
            public void onFragmentInteraction(int index);
        }
    }
    
    fragment_list.xml
    
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/ListFragment_layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ListFragment">
    
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:dividerHeight="32dp" />
    
    </FrameLayout>
    
    package com.example.tourguide;
    
    import android.content.res.Resources;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
    
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    
    import android.widget.ListView;
    
    /**
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
     * Use the {@link ListFragment#newInstance} factory method to
     * create an instance of this fragment.
     */
    public class ListFragment extends Fragment implements 
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
    {
        ListView listView;
        String[] array;
        String listStr;
        private OnFragmentInteractionListener listener;
    
    
    
        // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
        // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
        private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
        private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    
        // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
        private String mParam1;
        private String mParam2;
    
        public ListFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }
    
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment ListFragment.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        public static ListFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) 
        {
            ListFragment fragment = new ListFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
            args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (getArguments() != null)
            {
                mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
                mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup 
        container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, 
            false);
            listView = view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            array = 
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.string_array_cities);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> 
            (getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            return view;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int 
        index, long id)
        {
            if(listener != null)
            {
                listener.onFragmentInteraction(index); //pass index of array
            }
        }
    
        public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener
        {
            public void onFragmentInteraction(int index);
        }
    }
    
    activity_main.xml
    
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView1_list"
            android:name="com.example.tourguide.ListFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_list" />
    
        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView2_text"
            android:name="com.example.tourguide.TextFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_text" />
    </LinearLayout>
    
    package com.example.tourguide;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
    
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    TextFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, 
    ListFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener
    {
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public void onFragmentInteraction(int index)
        {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            TextFragment textFragment = 
   (TextFragment)manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView2_text);
            textFragment.updateTextView(index);
        }
    
    }
    
        strings.xml
    
        <resources>
        <string name="app_name">Tour Guide</string>
        <string name="hello_blank_fragment">Hello blank fragment</string>
        <string name="text_box">default</string>
        <string name="welcome">Welcome to the Tour Guide App</string>
    
        <string name="set_Richmond">Richmond is a quite city with many nice 
        hidden scenic places. A small town named Steveston is found on the 
        south 
        west part
        of the city and is well known for having good seafood and nice 
        places to visit like Garry Point and the west and south dykes. 
        </string>
    
        <string name="set_Vancouver">Vancouver is one of Canadas biggest 
        cities and has a lot to offer like the malls and many towers, 
        beaches, 
        parks.</string>
    
        <string name="set_Toronto">Toronto is Canadas biggest city on the 
        east coast and home to the TSX and Maple Leafs.</string>
    
        <string name="set_New_West">New West is a city east of Vancouver but 
        close by and has nice parks and ice rinks like Moody Park and Queens 
        Park.
        Queens Park home of the New West Royals.</string>
      
        <string name="set_Montreal">Monteal is famous for their smoked meat 
        and they speak french.</string>
    
        <string name="set_Aldergrove">Aldergrove is a quite town and is east 
        of Langley not too far and is a nice place.</string>
    
        <string-array name="string_array_cities">
            <item>Richmond</item>
            <item>Vancouver</item>
            <item>Toronto</item>
            <item>New West</item>
            <item>Montreal</item>
            <item>Aldergrove</item>
        </string-array>
    
    
    </resources>
```

The is the code for my android app it is a app that demonstrates how to communicate with multiple fragments in one activity. But the textview in the text fragment is not being updated after an item of the listview is selected. The textview should update when an item in the listview is selected but it is not updating, it is not crashing though.

Comment: What is the "crash" message? Something about that line?

Comment: not exactly showing anything its something to do with setAdapter... cause when I remove that line the app loads but I cant see the list or the items.

Comment: the stack trace

Comment: its not showing anything

Comment: Uninstall the app on the device or emulator and it should spit out a stack trace in the 'run' portion of AS next time. Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563492/setadapter-crashes-app or another previous question or the Android documentation answer your question?

Comment: I have included the exception above in the code at the bottom now thanks it says fatal exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems okay only a few lines of code need to be changed.

Inside **TextFragment** you need to remove textView initialization from onCreate(...){} method to onCreateView(....) like as follows:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(....){
 .......
 .....
 textView = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView1); //remove this line of code.
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(......){
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_text, container, false);
 textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView1); //you need to initialize textview here.
 return view;
}
```

And, Inside **ListFragment** you need to remove all code of initialization from onCreate(..){} to onCreateView(...){} like as follows:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(...){
 .......
 ....
 ...
 //remove all this code to another method.
 /*listView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
 //Resources res = getResources();
 array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.string_array_cities);
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
 listView.setAdapter(adapter);*/
}

@Override
 public View onCreateView(.....){
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
  listView = view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.string_array_cities);
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
  listView.setAdapter(adapter);
  return view;
 }
  // Add this code in your updated code.you need to override onAttach method
 @Override
 public void onAttach(@NonNull @NotNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener){
        listener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    }
    else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString());
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just confused as to why move it to onCreateView vs onCreate() why was it causing an error? Do I write all the code in OnCreateView for the fragments and write all the code in the main activity in onCreate() why is this? Thanks

Comment: yeah, it's because fragments and activity have different life cycles. The reason, you were getting crashed was because you were accessing views id's in the onCreate() method while actually the root layout was inflated in onCreateView(). In simple, you were accessing textview id even before it was inflated by the view. And, if this solved your problem please accept the answer and upvote. It will be helpful to me.

Comment: hey ah ok I will try to understand that, I have updated my code above but the textview is not changing for some reason, but it is not crashing now I have added the listener. Also it says that the upvote was recorded but not displayed till im level 15. If you can upvote the question maybe I can try again after. Thanks. Oh and also the checkmark accept worked.

Comment: hey were you able to figure it out? I am getting a null pointer exception for some reason I think my notes are from 2016 so some of these things are depreciated, still stuck : (

Comment: where did get the null pointer exception? show me logcat.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tourguide, PID: 22114
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.tourguide.ListFragment$OnFragmentInteractionListener.onFragmentInteraction(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.tourguide.ListFragment.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:88)
        at com.example.tourguide.ListFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onItemClick(Unknown Source:6)

Comment: I have added it in the comment above this one.. still cant figure it out it is the listener it says that it points to null when I remove the if statement:// if(listener != null)
            //{
                listener.onFragmentInteraction(index); //pass index of array
            //} then it will cause an exception because listener is pointing to null...

Comment: check the code again. I have updated it according to your latest problem.And, please upvote this one. I  have spent a lot of time on this.

Comment: hey it doesn't work it's still crashing : (

Comment: I had enough points to upvote you but it didnt work lol

Comment: It was right after you helped me the first time just moving it to OnCreateView I just had a small type lol...  textView = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView1); anyways thanks for the help I did vote you up thanks for everything and trying

Comment: happy to help.best wishes